# Get list of values from a table where there is a certain value

Tags: mysql

In the following query the user obtains all the details of a certain car; for example: wheels - red,seats - blue

```
SELECT mc.car_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.car_parts, ' - ', cd.car_detail) separator ',') AS 
detail_values
FROM my_cars mc          
LEFT JOIN cars_detail cd ON mc.id = cd.id_car
LEFT JOIN car_parts cp ON cd.id_parts = cp.id_parts
WHERE id_car = 1
GROUP BY car_name;
```

When the user does a search, for example used as a parameter the color 'red' should return exactly the same values; that is, the user wants to get all the details of a car where one of the details is the color 'red'

```
SELECT mc.car_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.car_parts, ' - ', cd.car_detail) separator ',') AS detail_values
FROM my_cars mc          
LEFT JOIN cars_detail cd ON mc.id = cd.id_car
LEFT JOIN car_parts cp ON cd.id_parts = cp.id_parts
WHERE id_car = 1
AND cd.car_detail LIKE 'red' //Illustrative example that returns a wrong result
GROUP BY car_name;
```

How to do this?

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f26b4/4

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` will become useless after you put the condition `WHERE cd.car_detail LIKE 'red'`.  Why `LEFT JOIN` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix for your criteria is use `exists` , If you apply filter on car properties `cars_detail` in same query the related rows will be filtered out and  `GROUP_CONCAT` will not show excluded properties of car.

```
SELECT mc.car_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.car_parts, ' - ', cd.car_detail) separator ',') AS detail_values
FROM my_cars mc          
LEFT JOIN cars_detail cd ON mc.id = cd.id_car
LEFT JOIN car_parts cp ON cd.id_parts = cp.id_parts
WHERE id_car = 1
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM cars_detail
  WHERE car_detail LIKE 'red'
  AND cd.id_car = id_car
)
GROUP BY car_name
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f26b4/7)